# Binding handlers to elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and wanted to deeply understand how handling events with event handlers work behind the scenes. Later, I came across this article https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-perform-event-handling-in-react-tutorial/ explaining how event handling works behind the scenes. This article says that "When you assign an event handler function to an element in JSX, React doesn’t actually attach an event listener to the underlying DOM element. Instead, it adds the function to an internal mapping of functions. There’s a single event listener on the document for the page. As events bubble up through the DOM tree to the document, the React handler checks to see whether any components have matching handlers".  By "it adds the function to an internal mapping of functions" does it mean that each component has its own internal mapping of functions? or does it mean that React takes all event handlers in an app overall and put all of those handlers in its internal mapping of functions?

Please guys help anyone. Please let me know if you are confused